# Handling static files that dont pertain to an app in Django

Tags: python, django

In the documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/

I read that static files should be put with their respective apps and called upon with

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<img src="{% static "articles/css/base.css" %}" alt="My image"/>
```

However later on in the docs it mentions that some static files don't pertain to a particular app. This is where `STATICFILES_DIRS` comes into play. If I read correctly `STATICFILES_DIRS` is a tuple for Django to use to look for other static files. I was wondering how would I call the static files that was called from the `STATICFILES_DIRS`?

ex: something like

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "/css/default.css" %}">`

Also I am not sure what to put for my `STATIC_ROOT`. Do I leave it empty? (`''`)

My proj tree

```
mysite
  \articles
       \static
       \articles
           \css
               base.css
  \static
       \images
       \css
           default.css
       \js 
  \templates
       base.html
  \settings.py
```

This is currently in my settings.py regarding static files

```
# looks for static files in each app
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)

STATICFILES_STORAGE = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.StaticFilesStorage'
)

# the absolute path to the directory where collectstatic will collect static files for deployment (OUTPUT)
STATIC_ROOT = ''

# This setting defines the additional locations the static files app will traverse if the FileSystemFinder finder is enabled.
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # used for static assets that aren't tied to a particular app
     os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)

# URL to use when referring to static files located in STATIC_ROOT
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Comment: Honestly, the documentation on static files is really confusing, and I've been using django for a while.

Comment: Try putting `/static/` as your `STATIC_ROOT`

Comment: `OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/static'` =/

Comment: Woops, try making it the full filesystem path to your static directory like this: `/path/to/mysite/static`

Comment: set STATIC_ROOT to anywhere else , but not site_root/static !!!

Comment: @Leonardo.Z are you suggesting contradicting the comment above yours?

Comment: I think the point he's trying to make is about site security, but you can deal with that later i.m.o.

Comment: I've seen some examples online where people left their `STATIC_ROOT = ''` which I am confused on why they can do this while i cannot

Comment: @notbad.jpeg Yea I've read around and people suggest not putting those files inside your project due to security reasons but I'll worry about it later because I just started learning Django

Comment: The officiall doc is quite clear: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#static-root

Comment: @Leonardo.Z I want to set `STATIC_ROOT` as empty but I get this error when I do so `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: You're using the staticfiles app without having set the STATIC_ROOT setting to a filesystem path.` Where should I set it?

Comment: I am posting an answer. Just wait a few mins

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost everything about django static is related to the `django.contrib.staticfiles` app. Although you need to custom edit many settings to make `staticfiles` work, what is does is simple. It provides a `collectstatic` command which collects static files from different app and put them into a single directory.

The answer to your first question is simple: Put those common static files under the `/static` directory of your django project directory. In your case, it's `mysite/static`.

Reason: First, it's the official way. You can find the following code in official doc:  [Managing static files (CSS, images)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/). Second, it's reasonable. Since we put static files only used in a single app under `project/appnane/static/...` The project's static dir should follow the same name pattern.

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"), # That's it!!
    '/var/www/static/',
)
```

As I said in the comment, your should not set `STATIC_ROOT` to `project_absolutr_path/static`. Because that directory is user to put css app static files. You don't want the collectstatics command to pollute that directory  especially when you are using a version control system like git/svn.

`STATIC_ROOT` really depends on the way you host these static files(Apache, Nginx, S3, CDN, Paas like heroku)

Comment: I appreciate your effort! It seems to me that `STATIC_ROOT` does depend on the situation. What if I were to host these files on heroku?

Comment: On heroku, you don't  have access to apache/nginx, so have to either host static with django itself, or use a cdn.

Comment: They have a detailed doc about it https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets

Comment: I am just confused because I still don't know what to input for `STATIC_ROOT` because as you said it depends on the situation.

Comment: If you use django itself to host static files on heroku, it's reasonable to put the collected files under a directory of your project (not 'static'). So you could set  STATIC_ROOT to `staticfiles`(or 'asserts', ). The link I posted (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets) mentioned that.