# django AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'rsplit'

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

Running `python manage.py check` throws an error `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'rsplit'`.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mieltn/django_projects/batch/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/mieltn/django_projects/batch/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/mieltn/.virtualenvs/django3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/mieltn/.virtualenvs/django3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/mieltn/.virtualenvs/django3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/mieltn/.virtualenvs/django3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/home/mieltn/.virtualenvs/django3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 301, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 855, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/mieltn/django_projects/batch/unesco/models.py", line 4, in <module>
    class Category(models.Model):
  File "/home/mieltn/.virtualenvs/django3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 320, in __new__
    new_class._prepare()
  File "/home/mieltn/.virtualenvs/django3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 333, in _prepare
    opts._prepare(cls)
  File "/home/mieltn/.virtualenvs/django3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 285, in _prepare
    pk_class = self._get_default_pk_class()
  File "/home/mieltn/.virtualenvs/django3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 238, in _get_default_pk_class
    pk_class = import_string(pk_class_path)
  File "/home/mieltn/.virtualenvs/django3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 13, in import_string
    module_path, class_name = dotted_path.rsplit('.', 1)
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'rsplit'
```

I saw [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22977285/attributeerror-tuple-object-has-no-attribute-rsplit-django) about such error and it doesn't seem to be the case. The problem is supposedly connected with models.py, because when the models file remains empty everything works fine. When I add

```
from django.db import models

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
```

check crashes.

I guess, there might be a silly mistake or mistype, I'm failing to capture. Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
settings.py looks as following

```
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-_w_1zo)mcg((=iko!2-1vqjf)dme9#la0rm=q2x5oe@c91%&!4'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django_extensions',
    'unesco.apps.UnescoConfig',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'batch.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'batch.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

EDIT 2:
unesco/apps.py has only UnescoConfig

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class UnescoConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField',
    name = 'unesco'
```

Comment: Could you please update the question with settings.py

Comment: Added setting.py after EDIT

Comment: Can you update `UnescoConfig` also?

Comment: Updated as well, was it a piece of code you were referring?

Comment: Can you check the answer and see if it answer your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django provides [**DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD** which is a default primary key](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field) field type to use for models that don’t have a field with `primary_key=True`. This can also be override on the [app level](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/applications/#configuring-applications) using
[`AppConfig.default_auto_field`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.default_auto_field). Since you override `default_auto_field` field on the app level it [gets priority compared to `settings.DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/db/models/options.py#L222).

Django then try to [import this string dynamically](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/db/models/options.py#L238). [As part of it, it then try to split the string into `module_path` and `class_name`.](https://github.com/django/django/blob/fb05ca420da1341c0d39cf1f0e2fb659be836c92/django/utils/module_loading.py#L25)

So answering your question, the issue is here

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class UnescoConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField',
    name = 'unesco'
```

This will treat `default_auto_field` as *tuple(Note the trailing comma)* instead of a string.

```
>>> myfield = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField',
>>> type(myfield)
<class 'tuple'>
>>> module_path, class_name = myfield.rsplit('.', 1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'rsplit'
```

Comment: Thanks, works fine after removing the comma! I still have a small question though. What would be the right way to deal with this problem? Why did django create app config in a tuple format? Is it safe just to remove the comma?

Answer (score 0):

I also was facing this error.
Here is my code

Setting.py

```
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'website.wsgi.application',
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.Account'
```

Solve Error by removing Comma

```
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'website.wsgi.application'
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.Account'
```