# Change django's default static directory

Tags: python, django, html5boilerplate

I got an issue with Django 1.6:

I want to change the default static file directory in django. I don't want it in 
`project/myapp/static` but in `project/static`

I readed django's documentation, added

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
STATICFILES_DIR =(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),)
```

In my settings.py

Then I ran `./manage.py collectstatic` and files copyed as expected.

Finally I launched the server, the app is using django boilerplate plugin, so my template begins with:

```
{% extends 'dh5bp/base.html' %}
{% load url from future %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% block head %}
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "css/homepage.css" %}">
{% endblock %}
```

And the Css won't load: But in my server log, I got that:

```
[29/Aug/2014 11:23:03] "GET /static/js/dh5bp/plugins.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[29/Aug/2014 11:23:03] "GET /static/css/homepage.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1657
```

As you see the statics file from dh5bp (Boiler plate plugin) Are loaded correctly, while the statics from my app aren't loaded correctly.

I tried to add `+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)` to my urls.py, right after urlpatterns, It didn't worked.

So please if someone could tell me chat I'm doing bad and what should I change in the settings. It could be great

EDIT:

Did tryed the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22976596/handling-static-files-that-dont-pertain-to-an-app-in-django), It give me the same result: only statics from boilerplate are loaded.

And not to mention that I've obviously checked if the files exists in /project/static, they does exists.

EDIT 2:

I tried to put the old static folder in my app, to ensure That he weren't looking for the files in the old folder. It doesn't, so I don't know where django expect those file to be? Is there a debug setup that could help on this?

Comment: how you set it up base_dir

Comment: @rajasimon `BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))`, The default configuration. I'm sure it's the good one as collectstatic did copied in the dir I wanted to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `STATIC_ROOT` shouldn't be in `STATICFILES_DIRS`.
`STATICFILES_DIRS` should contain paths to your project's static files.
`STATIC_ROOT` is where all your static files are collected when you run `collectstatic`.

If you run django server with DEBUG=True, server will serve static files straight form `STATICFILES_DIRS`, and if DEBUG=False it won't handle static files at all. In that case you can run django server with option `--insecure`.

See this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836674/) for more.

Comment: So according to this, If I change STATICFILES_DIRS To "staticApp", then placing all my app-related static files in it, it should works?

Comment: I don't know what "staticApp" is. If you mean "static" directory in your application, then yes, as long as you enable [AppDirectoriesFinder](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATICFILES_FINDERS)